# Transform a function into custom Aggregation using dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a large dataset with 3 columns:

```
   sku   center units
0   103896  1   2.0
1   103896  1   0.0
2   103896  1   5.0
3   103896  1   0.0
4   103896  1   7.0
5   103896  1   0
```

And I need to use a `groupby-apply` function using dask.

```
def function_a(x):
    return np.sum((x > 0).cumsum() == 0)

def function_b(x):
    return x.eq(0).sum()/((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum())


result1 = df.groupby([sku, center])['units'].apply(function_a).compute()
result2 = df.groupby([sku, center])['units'].apply(function_b).compute()
```

I am trying to convert these two functions, using [Dask Custon Aggreagtion function](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#custom-aggregation) in order to avoid data shuffling behind the scene:

[image]

However I am a bit confused on how to use `chunk, agg, finalize` arguments in a similar way as custom mean aggregation example:

```
custom_mean = dd.Aggregation(
     name='custom_mean',
     chunk=lambda s: (s.count(), s.sum()),
     agg=lambda count, sum: (count.sum(), sum.sum()),
     finalize=lambda count, sum: sum / count,
```

How to rewrite each step from :

```
np.sum((x > 0).cumsum() == 0)
```

in this format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preface

First, a small primer on what the arguments of [dask.dataframe.groupby.Aggregation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#custom-aggregation) do. There is also a good example about custom aggregation on their [website](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#aggregate) As I do not know in which format you have your data on disk, imagine the following: All of your rows are well shuffled and saved to a huge `.csv` file which is then split up into multiple smaller files. We will call these files 'partitions' for now, so each `.csv` file is one partition.

**Step 1**

Imagine you do a `.groupby(['sku', 'center'])` on each of your single files. The inputs to the `chunk` parameter will now be 'units' Series from all data in this chunk (which is almost certainly not all data from the group as the rows are shuffled). These rows are then combined to one (or multiple) output series per group.

**Step 2**

After we have done this, we want to combine all the 'output' series of all partitions with each other. So `agg` must be a function that takes (concatenated) outputs (per group) of the first step and should return another list of Series.

**Step 3**

As it is sometimes useful (e.g. when calculating the `mean` as in the example) to perform a single final operation when all data is combined (aka reduced), you can specify a `finalize` operation in the end, the input will be concatenated output series of the second step.

---

### Your Problem

Due to the nature of your functions, their performance cannot (easily) be achieved using custom aggregation. The problem is for custom aggregation to work, the operation must be able to work on chunks of the data (as with map/reduce in general). Let's have a closer look:

### `function_a()`: `np.sum((x > 0).cumsum() == 0)`

A cumulative sum requires its values (columns) to be in a well determined order for it to return a deterministic result. Meaning `cumsum([1, 2, 3]) = [1, 3, 6]` but `cumsum([2, 1, 3]) = [2, 3, 6]`. As specified in the [documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#custom-aggregation), the function in the `chunk` parameter should take arbitrary rows (of one partition, e.g.: a file on your drive) and combine them to some result. As the rows do not now their order within the group, this is cannot work as is.

### `function_b()`: `x.eq(0).sum() / ((x.eq(0) & x.shift().ne(0)).sum())`

A similar argument can be made for the second function. While it is trivial to perform `x.eq(0)` as well as `x.ne(0)`, the problem here comes with the `.shift()` operation. When you have an arbitrary set of rows, determining the shifted position cannot be done as easy.

---

### Possible solutions

All of this depends a lot on the size of your dataset in combination with the hardware that you have got. You will definitely need to sort your data at least once to create (or upon creating) an index, but you only have to do this once, as you can persist the result. As the [documentation states](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html):

> Cleverly parallelizable operations (fast):
>
> ### - `groupby-apply` on index: `df.groupby(['idx', 'x']).apply(myfunc)`, where `idx` is the index level name

So now I would first try to create an index on your data and then apply your functions as this should improve the speed:

```
# The 'id' column corresponds to your current index
# First create an index on ['sku', 'center']
# As dask does not support multiindexing, we will do this with a small hack
df['index'] = df.apply(lambda row: f'{int(row["sku"])}|{int(row["center"])}', axis=1, meta=str)

# Notice how we can now sort by 'id' to get a deterministic result
def function_a(x):
    return np.sum((x.sort_values('id')['units'] > 0).cumsum() == 0)

# Same sorting happens here
def function_b(x):
    x = x.sort_values('id')
    units = x['units']
    return units.eq(0).sum() / ((units.eq(0) & units.shift().ne(0)).sum())

result1 = df.groupby('index').apply(function_a, meta=int).compute()
result2 = df.groupby('index').apply(function_b, meta=float).compute()
```

Comment: Hello @BStadlbauer,

Thank you very much to clarify my understand about dask aggregation.

Comment: I am using hdf5 file, that contains about 70 M rows

Comment: I'll make some tests with your  suggestion. Thank you again

Comment: @Cesar You are welcome, you can read more about the internal workings of partitions [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html#partitions). Also, as said above, `.set_index()` requires (expensive) shuffling, `dask` provides several methods, you can read more about your options [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-groupby.html#shuffle-methods). Ideally you can set your index once and save it back to disk (hdf5). The next time you can then do a `.set_index(..., sorted=True`)